# Data in Combo Box in form not relfecting in Access Report

Tags: ms-access, binding, combobox, autofill

I have been battling with this problem for weeks now and simply cannot find a solution.

I am using MS Access 2007

I have a table caled "Policy Information" where all of my data is stored. I have created a combox box to autofill a few text fields using a query called "BC Allocation Query". By choosing from the combox269 field I created then 6 other text fields are automatically completed. I used the function =[Combo269].column in the control field of the text field I want auto-completed.

This all works great however I cannot seem to relfect the information from the text boxes which are auto-completed to relfect in my Access Reports whcih I have set up.

Please can someone assist me withthis before I jump off a cliff:)

Answer (score 2):

Are these text fields on the form bound to fields in the source for the form?  If not, they are unbound, and you need to write code to save this information into the table when you navigate away from the record or close the form.  If they are bound, you need to programmatically force a save of the record when VBA changes values, otherwise - you might get the dreaded 'values changed by another user' verbage in an error.